# How to filter dates within a range in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a df where I'd like to filter the table by a single date column, specifically dates that are within 1 year of today.

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
df[df['latest start date'] > (date.today() + timedelta(weeks=-52))]
```

The error message I get is:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Transform your date to `datetime`: `df['latest start date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['latest start date'] )` before that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date column is not of type date.

```
df['latest start date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['latest start date'])
```

Now you can compare the two because they are both of type datetime

Comment: One step closer, thank you. However I now get this TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date

Comment: Actually, I solved it. Just amended the formula to this df[df['latest start date'] > (datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(weeks=-52))] after your suggestion.

Comment: Glad I could help, yep datetime and date are different I should have caught that